# React - how to update state with dynamic properties without defining it in state first?

Tags: reactjs

```
const [number, setNumber] = React.useState({})
```

The way Im doing it below does not work:

```
   setNumber(prevNumber => ({
  ...prevNumber,
  [num]: (prevNumber[num] + 1) || 0,
}))
```

The only way to get it to work is when i define the properties as below:

```
const [number, setNumber] = React.useState({
 1: 0,
 2: 0,
 3: 0,
 4: 0,
 5: 0,
})
```

I dont know how many properties I will have (maybe 1-5 or 1-10 for example) and dont want to pre define all of them. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Update: 'full code':

```
// what i get is:{4: 4, 5: 1}
//what I wanted and get if i have initialState is:   {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 4, 5: 1}
const reviews = [
  { title: "movie1", rating: 4 },
  { title: "movie2", rating: 5 },
  { title: "movie3", rating: 4 },
  { title: "movie4", rating: 4 },
  { title: "movie4", rating: 4 }
];
function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState({ 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0 });

  const func = (num) => {
    setNumber((prevNumber) => ({
      ...prevNumber,
      [num]: (prevNumber[num] || 0) + 1 || 0
    }));
  };
  const getNumbers = () => {
    return reviews.map((review) => {
      func(review.rating);
    });
  };

  console.log("number: ", number);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={getNumbers}>helo</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you are having a "type" issue, just define your state var as "any". Ex: 
const [number, setNumber] = React.useState<any>({})

But remember: using the "any" type is not a good practice and must be avoided

Answer (score 1):

prevNumber[num] could be undefined, so you need a fallback for that.

Try this:
`[num]: ((prevNumber[num] || 0) + 1) || 0,`

After clarifying what you need, here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7z54om9b/1/).

Since you do not have the numbers below 4, they will never be set because num will never be 1 for example.

So you would need to check if the numbers below are already present and if not, fill those with 0.

```
const lowerNumbers = Array.from(Array(num)).reduce((aggregate,_,i) => {
    aggregate[i] = aggregate[i] || 0
    return aggregate
    }, {
      ...prevNumber,
      [num]: (prevNumber[num] || 0) + 1
    })
    return lowerNumbers
  });
```

This takes the current numbers, adds one to the number that will be increased.
It creates an array with the lower numbers and checks if those are already present and if not, fills them with 0.

`{ "0": 0, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 4, "5": 1 }`

Comment: actually it works, im not getting errs anymore, but the fallback doesnt work fully. if prevNumber[num] is undefined, it stays undefined, it will not be 0 in such case unless again I predefine it as 0 in state

Comment: So if you use this code, and you call it with num = 1, 1 will not be 1 afterwards?

Comment: I update my question and added more code so its more clear

Comment: It works. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toc6qn1z/). And you do not have to declare anything within the rating object to update. I don't know why you took back that this fixes your problem though. Are you sure you are adding an empty obejct to the useState with ({})

Comment: but in the fiddle it also not works or maybe i wasnt clear what im trying to have. in the i fiddle only properties 4 and 5 are shown (those that have values), others not. I wanted others with value 0 not to be ignored and dont understand why this happens, so instead of how it is now { "4": 16, "5": 4 }, I want to have {1:0, 2:0, 3:0,  4: 16, 5: 4 } and if y reviews had not 5 but lets say 10 objects its would go up to 10